# Returning Multiple Results with Match Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am looking for matches of information in Column E of one worksheet to Column E of a second worksheet.

I've used:
    =MATCH("*"&E1&"*",'SHEET1'!E:E,0)

and this returns me which row the match is in.

However I have multiple hits on my search, but it is only returning me the row of the first hit.

Is there a way to get a list of all hits, not just the first occurrence?
Thank you!

Comment: Use .Find and .FindNext to loop through all search results...

Comment: =IF(""&E1&""='SHEET1'!E2:E100,ROW('SHEET1'!E2:E100)).  If you highlight the formula and press F9 you can see all of the occurrences that get returned. This is the first step. The next step depends on what you where you want to go from here. Also note, when doing this formula in particular, do not reference the whole column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say *Sheet1* is like:

[image]

and in the other sheet, there is a ***12*** in cell **E1**

then pick a cell and enter the *Array Formula*:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(Sheet1!E:E=$E$1,ROW(Sheet1!E:E)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!E:E))+1,""),ROW(A1)),"")
```

and copy down to display:

[image]

*Array formulas* must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

NOTE:  This kind of *array formula* can be **painfully slow!**  Personally, I would replace all the **E:E** with **$E$1:$E$999999** to improve the speed.

Comment: Referencing the whole column E with this type of formula will really pay a toll on your computer as you noted. The range should be made to reference the current data, such as "E2:E1000".